# Assign the value of merged cells to all the adjacent cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to automatically assign the value of merged cell to all the adjacent cells in the same range without unmerging and manually entering them for each item. I have the below structure:

In column A, I have my clusters that are merged to cover the related range in column B. So merged cluster 1 cover items 1-3, and merged cluster 2 to cover items 4-5.

```
A.                 B. 
Cluster 1          Item 1
                   Item 2
                   Item 3
Cluster 2          Item 4
                   Item 5
```

Now I need to do some analysis on the items, and I need to know what is the cluster of each item without unmerging clusters in column A. I thought to add a helper column where I take the value from merged cells and assign it individually to each item next to it. This would give me the necessary input for the analysis. However the challenge is that new items can be added to the cluster by users thus as soon as someone adds new item to the cluster it should get the cluster ID assigned to it autamatically.  Any idea if this would be possible with some formula or simple VBA?

Comment: If Column c where your helper column.  Put this in C2 and copy down a few thousand rows or 100,000 if your data will get that big. `=IF(B2<>"",IF(A2<>"",A2,C1),"")`

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks a lot, the formula addresses the first part of my problem as it assigns the cluster IDs to each item; however it doesn't help with the second part, which is if someone adds a new item to a cluster (new row within the cluster to enter the new item) one still needs to automatically enter the formula to that new row to get its cluster-ID.

Comment: No just copy the formula down the while column. It will return an empty string till some puts in an item.

Comment: Thanks, Scott, what i mean is that every time a new row is inserted into the clusters to add new item, I need to manually drag the formula down again, it doesn't automatically copy the formula to the newly inserted rows.

Comment: Then you will need vba.

Comment: Sheets like this should be output sheets and not input sheets.  Your input sheets should have the data normalized and then you create the output to "Look" correct.  But the data sheet is always normalized.